# Would this Alien race take over?

Tags: internal-consistency, aliens, government, xenobiology, invasion

If 1,000 Aliens **secretly** invaded earth would they take over the earth and start anew?

These Aliens crash landed on our planet long ago, so their technology for the most part is destroyed. The only thing they manage to retained are advanced weapons that can destroy Nuclear Weapons without nuclear fallout occurring.

These Aliens have the special and unique ability to change/manipulate their cellular structure. (They have complete control over their anatomies and bodies of themselves, including skin, nails, fat, muscles, blood, metabolism, nerves, etc., allowing them to freely alter and manipulate them. For example they can grow additional appendages and body-parts, remove them or otherwise manipulate them, in visible, chemical and cellular/sub-cellular levels.)

Each one are in the main Countries there are 10 stationed per country these countries are: Russia, Italy, Brazil, India, France, United Kingdom, Germany, Japan, China, and The United States of America. The other 900 are located in other countries but are meant to stay incognito until they are given the signal.

These Aliens goal are to start anew. To become the apex species of Earth and rule. Their government for now is kind of like a council. The ten in each country share a collective hive mind. **Only these certain ten in each country have the hive mind.** So the ten in France share a hive mind with each other, the ten in china share a hivemind with each other, etc etc.

They can also reproduce with humans and other Aliens. They take on average 5 months before the child is born and they generally have more than one kid per pregnancy. They can become female or male depending on how they changed their bodies.

Their shape-shifting abilities are detailed enough to bypass highly sensitive eye-scans and voice-scans.

They are basically immortal as they can stay young forever. They can be killed only in a few ways, destroying their brain 100% completely, though few modify themselves to avoid suffering that fate. Completely destroying their bodies is another way. Though keeping them locked up is a option but it is not easy.
How would they go about taking over?

EDIT: While pregnant they can not use their shape changing abilties at all. They are basically human with a weak healing factor while pregnant

Comment: Could you tell us more about your aliens, how they coordinate, what their cellular structure manipulation is...

Comment: Also, you know taking over the USA and taking over the world is a *very* different thing?

Comment: @PatJ I know that it is but each country has a different government and this might get put on hold if its too vague. And I will be sure to edit the stuff you asked about in.

Comment: I think you should change the edit. Starting from the USA is too limiting, and you ask about the rest of the world either way.

Comment: @MathewStone where could they possibly start then? Cause this question might be put on hold for being vague.

Comment: I think the question is too vague more in the sense of what you mean by 'take over'.

Comment: Okay, just several details I think I might help. Where (location of aliens. Are they spread 20 per state? Or are they spread 1 alien power 10M people?)

Comment: Tech (you said they lost MOST of their tech. Did they retain anything worth noting?)

Comment: @Arthew III He means shapeshifting.

Comment: And what @Matthew Stone said. Do you mean a loss of all our governments? Or do you mean total eradication of humans?

Comment: I think I answered most of the questions right?

Comment: How do they die? Can the aliens even die? Given the ability to change/manipulate the cellular structure with the ability to grow body parts, they could simply fix any wounds inflicted to them right away. If the aliens can die, then the answer is "no - they cannot take over the word." If they cannot die, then the answer is "they'll take over the world.

Comment: Made an Edit does this change things over all?

Comment: I would be curious about what hell of a world pushed towards such characteristics; a shape-shifter is the "ultimate chamaeleon" and mimetic abilities are for the weak or the stealth predator. Starfaring races would be neither. They seem much more some artificially engineered bridgehead of an impending invasion than poor guys marooned on this Earth. Being able to reproduce with humans is another scarcely believable aspect. Being so filled with Handwavium you can really do whatever you please, from having one of them elected for president to have them die because some unexpected dietary problem.

Answer (score 7):

As this has the "reality-check"-tag:
*These Aliens crash landed on our planet long ago, so their technology, for the most part, is destroyed.* - not possible, especially for morphing creatures.

Why are traits like *immortal*, *hive-minded*, *two+ children in one birth with 0.5-year pregnancy*, *capable to breed with humans* (I guess the results are aliens and humans) *morphing* important to such high-level creatures?

Why are these traits relevant to replacing humans?

Just simple - procreate, multiply.

Be better than humans, take management positions in banks, government, etc. (and human offsprings will be valuable almost in same way as their alien sisters and brothers)

They will take over in no time and replace humanity in less than 1000 years.

Comment: Made an Edit does this change things over all?

Comment: @KawaiiSamii no, their healing abilities are irrelevant for my strategy. U current Q is good as it is - can they take over - yes. But ability to do that way not necessary means they will do it such way - psychology thing as example.or they act in groups up 1500 aliens per task, because of culture. There are lot of possibilities to make it more interesting, if you find that way to hard to describe or not interested in. Think more about your aliens, about their psychology, ask new questions.

Answer (score 4):

"the only technology they manage to retain are advanced weapons that can destroy nueclear weapons without fallout"

Why is this the technology they choose to keep?

If they have advanced weaponry stronger than humanity's strongest most terrible weapons, then they can wipe out entire cities with ease.

They could invade secretly, but there's not much point when they can simply wipe out the current inhabitants and start a new purebred race of their own species.

If your aliens truly want to hide, give them technology that can help them hide, or none at all, since they seem to be perfectly capable of hiding very well.

Perhaps though, they may have a weakness that allows someone to see through their cover, for the sake of conflict.

Currently these creatures are totally capable of taking over the earth unopposed, and, depending on whether their methods are peaceful, like in the answer above, or violent, they could overtake the human race very quickly.

Comment: "They could invade secretly, but there's not much point when they can simply wipe out the current inhabitants and start a new purebred race of their own species."  Slaves. Or food.

Comment: Made an Edit does this change things over all?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the details of your *current* question (which sounds as though it has changed a lot from the original version), it seems to me that they **would likely succeed** in taking over.

- They are effectively immortal, *and* can reproduce as well, which means that time is very much on their side.  In addition to the sheer capacity for population growth, they can build power bases, accumulate wealth and knowledge and skill at unheard of levels.
- Even with its range limits, the hive mind capabilities are a powerful advantage.  Anything that anyone learns (in each country) is known to all of them.  In a true hive mind that means not just information, but skills.  How powerful the hive mind is depends on how quickly and fully the aliens can access it, and whether new descendants will be plugged into the country-hives.
- They can blend in, and evade, better than anyone.  Someone gets suspicious?  Move and change your body to be a completely different person.
- Speaking of which, it sounds like they could replace key people of power.  Military commanders, businessmen, politicians, presidents.  We know that they can physically take their exact form, perfectly, down to fingerprints and DNA.  That means identical voice is possible as well.  Manner of speech and psychological traits might be more difficult for them to reproduce.
- They are motivated.  Unless there is strife within their society, they are a fairly large group [even initially] which is unified towards a particular goal.

A few comments on parts of your scenario that may complicate your storyline;

- The anti-nuke tech seems pretty useless.  Nukes are never a threat to them, since they're fully blended into human society.  Perhaps they could use it at some point to cripple a country, by taking out all of its nuclear power plants.
- The ability to reproduce with humans seems complicated.  Would hybrid progeny still have the full set of capabilities of the alien race?  If no, what's different?  Certainly these hybrids would be conflicted individuals, who feel somewhere between super-human, and sub-alien.  Likewise the 5 month gestation period would be highly suspicious to the human parent [if they're around], and any decent OBGYN.

You could use some of that to add interest to your story.  For example, the biggest threat to the alien race might just be their half-alien descendents.

Answer (score 3):

I just up-voted several of the previous things; the answer to your question is Yes, they would take over, so easily the plot is boring and nobody will care if they do.

You have made your "hero" (the aliens) too powerful, this is like asking if my neighbor Joe will be able to eradicate the ants that have chosen to colonize his garden: Yes, yes he can, and he did it by heroically driving to the hardware store, heroically spending  \$10 for some powder, and then heroically sprinkling it on the ant pile for about sixty seconds.

An interesting story demands equalized heroes and villains; or underdog heroes against more powerful villains. A one-sided fight is predictable, so nobody is turning the page to see how this will turn out or the hero can possibly win. That is a boring story!

As described, your aliens cannot possibly be in any serious danger. Pregnant women indistinguishable from humans are not going to be "detected". They move; how long they were pregnant can be covered by lies: My husband got a new job here and we had to move, so here we are, six months pregnant... (when it was really two).

As mentioned, they can impersonate anybody, rob banks and blame the officers, steal from safes, kill and replace powerful politicians, etc. The hive mind makes them perfect collaborators: They can kill and replace top management of a major corporation, or the police force.

You have to make them MUCH less powerful to have an interesting story.

Comment: P.S. One way of doing that: Make reproduction for immortals require many years of pregnancy, or perhaps make the window of conception only occur once per decade. Or eleven years to match the sunspot cycle.

Comment: If a pregnancy takes 6 months and all 1000 aliens are female by choice, then they roughly double every six months. Coordinating so each is only pregnant once per 2 years (emulating young humans), their pop doubles every 2 years; so in 40 years (20 gen) and being immortal they have multiplied their population by $2^{20}=1,048,576$: A billion of them.Another 3 gen (6 yrs) and they overwhelm the current population; along the way using up resources & both directly and indirectly preventing human procreation. Their adults take over "naturally", running nations, military, police, UN, etc. Too easy!

Comment: Or, they can only reproduce with humans, and need to take some kind of neutral form in order to do so.  Something strange and obvious... skin turns blue, they start glowing, whatever.  Still with immortality, hive mind capabilities, and cellular-level morphing abilities, they are likely still overpowered.

Answer (score 2):

You have a pretty interesting premise, depending on how you choose to use it. If you decide to go with it as a straight-up conspiracy takeover, they'll obviously be successful without an issue.

What I see potential for is a situation in which they *indirectly* destroy humanity. Not through direct, successful plotting, but rather through a failed attempt, followed by skillful evasion. I could see the aliens attempting a coup, but not having properly planned for it. Following this, word gets out worldwide, and humans start organizing witch hunts for the *indistinguishable* aliens.

Over time, the hysteria and paranoia of the unseen invader applying constant pressure to the collective human psyche eventually breaks something. Local militia tearing apart neighborhoods, marshal law, strict curfews, the curtailing of personal freedoms.Eventually the aliens will have taken over earth not through action, but rather inaction.

Here we see the aliens not so much as an external antagonist, but rather as a catalyst for humanity's own demise. For an even more poignant message, the aliens could have accidentally revealed themselves without any harmful intentions.

I find great sci-fi does is best to teach us about ourselves in a somewhat removed setting, so that we may be an outside observer to our own condition.

> *It is science fiction that holds a mirror to this age
>
>    - Brian Aldiss*

Answer (score 1):

**No, they would not take over. Once found, they would be destroyed very quickly.**

How would they be found? Well, the moment they tried to take over they would have exposed themselves.

"They can be killed only in a few ways, destroying their brain 100% completely, though few modify themselves to avoid suffering that fate. Completely destroying their bodies is another way." - **We don't need nukes to completely destroy a body (or a brain).** Grenades, and large missiles do a fantastic job of blowing bodies to bits.

Comment: And how to find them? That is, identify individual ones? If they breed and bide their time, they'd overwhelm us.

Answer (score 1):

Easily.

So far this collection of aliens seem to be immortal. As @MolbOrg stated all they need to do is multiply. You say it takes 5 months to get 2 or more extra aliens. So, in five months you have a minimum of 3000 aliens. Still not very impressive except for the fact that they are IMMORTAL. Remember you said aliens survive if they retain party of their brain, go octopus . You can easily populate humans.

This all seems kinda boring to me so here's the other option for a fast and easy destruction of most humans on earth. Nukes!. Shape shifting aliens are trying to destroy earth via our own nukes. They shape shift, I'm sure they can find our nukes. They then send nukes everywhere, MAD comes into effect, and the works ends as we know it. Immortal aliens stay in non nuked areas (the mountains).
The only downside is that they have to deal with radiation for a long time.

Comment: Made an Edit does this change things over all?

Answer (score 0):

This is your story and they will take over if you want them to take over.

It feels like the most important variable is kind of random : do they get found out by the humans ?

If not, they have no reason not to be able to take over, they are basically a better version of us. As MolbOrg said, just procreate and multiply.

However, if they do get found out, things get interesting althought once again depends on your story. As Aify said, humans are pretty good at killing off other species, and we'd be very keen on killing them if they are trying to take over. On both sides, strategies can be thought up to beet the other species but considering we are over 7 billion with access to a huge amount of technology and thousands of years of experience killing each other, I'm guessing humans would win.

The end result of a fight against humans and these aliens would obviously depend on how soon humans find out that a bunch of aliens are living among us and are trying to take over.

Answer (score 0):

So since nukes are in play, a critical componant of winning Globalthermal Nuclear Warfare is not to play... which is actually, why we had so many.  It wasn't enough to be able to launch first, but launch second (second-strike capability).  This relies on being able to see the inbound nukes with enough lead time to get all your nukes firing back.  It was estimated in a first strike, 97% of your entire aresenal will be nutralized by the enemy.  So aresanals were built with the understanding that 3% was enough harm the enemy enough on second strike to ensure a proper stand-off.   It was MAD (in every sense of the reading of those letters).

So here I am, an alien, watching these soon to be subject humans panic because on group put their primative nuclear missles too close to the other group and the other group is willing to start a war over this?  If only they knew I could save them all.  They'd practically do anything I said all because I have this one... small... gun...

Back to nuclear warfare for a moment... the whole point here isn't to have a gun you want to fire, it's to have a gun that you just so happen to be cleaning when your daughter daughter brings her boyfriend home and you want to impress upon the lad how comitted you are to your daughter than to your own continued livelyhood as you know it.  Of course, you'd never shoot the gun... you just need to that kid to think there is a situation where you would shoot that gun.

Back to the alien's plan... so okay... we couldn't have known our meeting with the President during his trip to Dallas would have gone down the way it did... and okay, this cold war is cooling off... I wait twenty years to when Reagan comes back and rattles a few cages about the nuclear threat and then I go to him and say "Mr. President, I have this gun... it can stop your enemies nukes... but only I can use it... now, I'll keep you safe from your enemies... but I need some compensation from you, Mr. President... I'll let you know what I need when I need it... of course, if you don't want too... I have friends in Moscow... and Kennedy was on his way to give me his answer in Dallas and we all know how that turned out."

That last one would be because as a Shape-Shifting alien, I like to keep the conspiracy theories going... and besides... I'm not lying... trip didn't turn out so well for both of us, Kennedy would have lept at the chance, what with his staunch anti-commie policies so he would be on his way to give me an answer, and I never said anything about me personally involved in that day.   With that message delivered to Reagan, I head off to celebrate.  After all, I'm pretty sure I made the most powerful man on the planet a deal he couldn't refuse and all I had to do was show him just one of our guns... now, I eliminated his greatest threat, am rewarded with just about anything on this planet I could want, and didn't lose a single of my very limited troops or my even more limited weapons.  I think I'll go see that Taxi film my human friend Hinkly has been raving about.  I don't see how any of this could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The shape changing ability alone is enough to allow them to live along side humans without discovery.

Having children with humans may not help them since they are the ones carrying the child. If a human female can carry the alien baby then they think the baby is premature at 5 months. (you may have to expand on that part since the baby probably doesn't have a clue how to control its form and would be born looking like the original alien until it did.)

Another thing you have to tell us is at what age do they become sexually mature.

If they are going for maximum growth rate then they would all be female in form so they can get pregnant. If they get pregnant twice a year they will hit 5000 new aliens in a year. I'm going to assume that they want to blend in so they can't just pop out 5000 every year without drawing attention so they stick to 5000 let them mature and then have them all become female and deal with breeding while the original 1000 worry about hiding and organization. If it takes 10 years to reach maturity and they wait the 10 years each time, just to keep the math simple, then the grown rate would be:

1000 year 1.

5000 year 2.

17,000 year 12.

81,000 year 22.

401,000 year 32.

2,001,000 year 42.

10,001,000 year 52...

In 50 years they hit 10 million. And that number is assuming they wait 10 years before having a burst of children. It would most likely be much faster and the kids spread out a bit more than twice in a year but the effect would be the same. In 10 years they would have enough to really take control of an area so they could grow undisturbed. In 20 years they would have communities all over.

Before all of that once the initial group was done with the first group of kids they would place themselves in charge of the nuclear powers of the world and not even need their anti nuke weapon.

Others have brought up what if they are found out and I think it is quite possible for them to be found out during child birth if the baby doesn't come out human. Also what happens when they die? Some are going to get into car accidents and have autopsies performed on them. Do they turn back? Are the organs obviously not human? Assuming they do look human are they human at a cellular level? Will a blood test show they aren't what they appear to be? Those first 10 to 20 years are going to be really tough for them. Too many mistakes they can't cover up and they are toast.

This means they may need to take over a third world country or someplace where the government has complete control over the media such as North Korea then they can handle the mistakes till they get their numbers up and figure out solutions.